# android image on bottomtoolbar not showing

Tags: android

I have a bottomtoolbar that its image not showing properly as the below[image]

this is the main menu

```
<item android:id="@+id/home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:gravity="left"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/News"
    android:icon="@drawable/news"
    android:title="Latest News"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:gravity="left"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:gravity="left"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

the inforamtion for:
Home icon : 140X125 png 32 bit color 1.52k
News icon : 127X117 png 32 bit color 6.70k

Comment: use Imagebutton insted of item

Comment: Since the icons are set in the same way the first icon is set, then, the problem COULD be the image resources you are using could not be decoded properly, try using different images and let us see the result

Comment: @CoolGuyCG i tried many images from the internet , from several image one worked but other didnt , wiy is that ?

Comment: @PranavAshok well i am using <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: @Moudiz make sure the image is png and use app:itemBackground="" to load the image

Comment: @PranavAshok its png and i got error R. unresolved

Comment: @Moudiz, use a vectordrawable from the design library as an icon. Their icons may be what you are actually looking for. In Android Studio, right click drawable->New->Vector Asset->Icon and select any matching your demand.

Comment: just clean your project and do File>Invalidate Cache / Restart>Invalidate and Restart and make android:orderInCategory="102" for id Search